# Need help setting up migration for node / Knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I just created a node application using knex.js and I need help on how to create a migration based on this sql dump. Would be really happy if someone could help me that has experience with Knex.

I don't ask for the whole thing, I just need some help on how to get started. I'm still really bad at javascript and I feel stuck :(

```
--
-- Table structure for table `role`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `role`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `authority` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `authority` (`authority`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `role`
--

LOCK TABLES `role` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `role` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES (1,'ROLE_ADMIN'),(2,'ROLE_USER');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `role` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user`
--

LOCK TABLES `user` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1,'$2a$10$BCYu4wAXWMDXpjnqb9PdSeNi2lUtqRCHvUYv6oWxaOKjEgiJN4Sz2','Admin'),(2,'$2a$10$Pv8Y8BDxeiSbg6yb/CMdrOD0z2Z3FZb3R/DfwW2zGXIEFvAbyQp7y','Rob7');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `user_role`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_role`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `user_role` (
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `role_id` (`role_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_role_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_role_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_role`
--

LOCK TABLES `user_role` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user_role` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `user_role` VALUES (1,1),(2,2);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user_role` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2016-03-08 12:00:23
```

Here is how I started:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {  
    return Promise.all([
      knex.schema.createTable('role', function(table){
        table.string('username');
        table.string('password');
        table.timestamps();
      }),
      knex.schema.createTable('user', function(table){
        table.string('username');
        table.string('password');
        table.timestamps();
      }),
      knex.schema.createTable('user_role', function(table){
        table.string('username');
        table.string('password');
        table.timestamps();
      })
    ])
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so first let's take a look at the role table. First thing we have is a primary key 'id' which auto-increments. So, the corresponding knex line would be this:

```
t.increments('id').primary().unsigned();
```

Then, we have authority. This is a unique varchar, which corresponds to a knex string. The equivalent line would be this:

```
t.string('authority', 255).unique();
```

Ok, now on to the users table. We have a primary, unique, auto-incrementing ID as before, so we can copy and paste the ID line from above. Then, we have username and password fields, which are NOTNULL varchars max 255, and username being unique. We can represent this using the following knex lines:

```
t.string('username', 255).notNull().unique();
t.string('password', 255).notNull();
```

Now, we just need to do our lines for the user_role table. First, we need to add an ID column as before. Then, we can add our foreign key columns like this:

```
table.integer('user_id').unsigned().references('user.id');
table.integer('role_id').unsigned().references('role.id');
```

When we put it all together, we'll get this:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {  
    return knex.schema.createTable('role', function(table){
      table.increments('id').primary().unsigned();
      table.string('authority', 255).unique();
      table.timestamps();
    }).createTable('user', function(table){
      table.increments('id').primary().unsigned();
      table.string('username', 255).notNull().unique();
      table.string('password', 255).notNull();
      table.timestamps();
    }).createTable('user_role', function(table){
      table.increments('id').unsigned().primary();
      table.integer('user_id').unsigned().references('user.id');
      table.integer('role_id').unsigned().references('role.id');
      table.timestamps();
    })
  ])
};
```

The above code will create all the tables, columns, etc, however it will not insert values. We will need to create a seedfile for that. We can create a seedfile to insert values, which will look like this:

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('users').del()
    .then(function () {
      // Inserts seed entries
      return knex('users').insert([
        {
          id: 1,
          username: "Admin",
          password: "$2a$10$BCYu4wAXWMDXpjnqb9PdSeNi2lUtqRCHvUYv6oWxaOKjEgiJN4Sz2"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          username: "Rob7",
          password: "$2a$10$Pv8Y8BDxeiSbg6yb/CMdrOD0z2Z3FZb3R/DfwW2zGXIEFvAbyQp7y"
        }
      ]);
    });
};
```

You'll want to create a new seedfile for each table, following the format above. I believe this answer should cover everything, but if you have any questions let me know!

### Rolling back

To roll back, we need to add an exports.down method to our migration. It should look like this:

```
exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.dropTable("role");
    knex.schema.dropTable("user");
    knex.schema.dropTable("user_role");
  ]);
};
```

Comment: Oh my god you are a kind man!! I'm forever greatful
I'll try settting it up asap. One question that just popped up: 
the seed file, where should it be put? And will knex automaticly find that if I run knex migrate:latest?

Comment: Glad I could help! Create the seedfiles by running `knex seed:make seed_name`. Then, to run the seeds, you will need to run `knex seed:run` from your project directory.

Comment: Hi again @Ryan Z
I tried deploying it to my cluster and I got: failed with error: alter table user_role add constraint user_role_user_id_foreign foreign key (user_id) references users (id) - ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN: Cannot add foreign key constraint Error: ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: So two questions: Instead of Promise.All, should I use do one promise with .then()? Second question, I tried rolling back and it said: Already at the base migration ( how do I roll back first migration? )

Comment: @Codehiker I believe the error you're getting is due to a charset mismatch. Check your cluster and see what the charsets are for all of the ID columns, and for the user_id and role_id columns. To rollback the migration, you will need to add an `exports.down` to the knex migration. I'll add this in my answer.

Comment: @Codehiker nevermind on my comment about the errors you got. The migration has a typo - instead of `users.id` and `roles.id` it should be `user.id` and `role.id`. I updated the code in my answer. I've also added code to my answer on how to roll back.

Comment: UserDB : | latin1  | latin1_swedish_ci 
and my knexfile.js uses charset: 'utf8'. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Codehiker the charset your knexfile is saved in doesn't matter. However, you will want to add the proper charset to your migrations. After each field in your migration, add `.charset('latin1_swedish_ci')`. So, for example, `table.increments('id').primary();` becomes `table.increments('id').primary().charset('latin1_swedish_ci');`

Comment: I didnt mean it was saved with it, the knex configuration can take a charset property like; 

    connection: {
      host: process.env.MYSQLHOST || 'localhost',
      user: process.env.MYSQLUSER || 'root',
      password: process.env.MYSQLPASSWORD || 'XXXX',
      database: process.env.MYSQLDB || 'test1',
      charset: 'utf8'
    }

Comment: Oh, I see. You should set the charset in your knexfile to match whatever charset your database is using.

Comment: Got it :) Seems like I cant reroll first migration though. Says  Already at the base migration. And again I really appreciate your time....

Comment: No problem! I'm guessing that you're getting that error because knex did not complete the migration due to the foreign key errors. Make sure the charset is specified in the knexfile, and that you have updated your migration code to match the new code block in my answer. After that you should be good to run.

Comment: I have updated both charset & your new migration & added the .down method. I can't run knex migrate:rollback because then I get the "Already at base error". And I dont think I can do migrate:latest either with the new code without deletting the tables. Is it fine to delete the tables from CLI instead?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. Delete the tables then re-run the migration.

Comment: New error :D.. :
Knex:warning - migrations failed with error: alter table `user_role` add constraint user_role_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `user` (`id`) - ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: That's not an error I've seen before. Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/245), I think we need to change the id columns to be unsigned, by adding `.unsigned()` to each. I updated the answer with this.

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: @Codehiker Great! Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: I got one but not sure if you know the deployment part. I'm pushing this to a docker registry & deploy it to a kubernetes kluster ( rancher / azure AKS ). 
Somehow I need this to run before my docker container runs and my mysql isn't in the container, so it cant be ran during docker build. 

In my deployment yml I added command: ["/bin/sh","-c"] args: ["knex migrate:latest"] which works, however thats the only thing that runs regardless if the migration passes or fails, it doesnt exec the docker-container after.

Comment: @Codehiker I have used knex in production. I put the production configuration into the knexfile using environment variables (see [this knexfile](https://github.com/theprinciPALS/chat_api_server/blob/master/knexfile.js)). Then, set the environment variables in rancher/AKS with the info of your production DB. Once you've done that, add a database migration line to your dockerfile. I have a dockerfile [here](https://github.com/theprinciPALS/chat_api_server/blob/master/Dockerfile), which calls a script, entrypoint.sh, that will run the migrations and then start the server.

Comment: @RyanZ Please fix your answer to not use `Promise.all` for running multiple queries "in parallel" that causes many problems in some cases. Chaining createcommands should be done with .then() or by just chaining them like ´.createTable(...).createTable(...)...`. The only reason why it works in this case is, becuase knex has internally created transaction to which all those queries are added so they are actually ran in a serial manner through the same connection.